# How to make program print a string for every item in a numerical list according to the value of the item in the list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for item in numbers:
    print("...")
```

This just prints the string for each item in the list, but I don't know how to make it print said string by the number of times as the item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you are allowed to use [multiplication (`*`) between an integer and a string](https://www.pythoncentral.io/use-python-multiply-strings/) which should do what you want.

```
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for item in numbers:
    print(item * "...")
```

Result is

```
...............
......
...............
......
......
```

Comment: THANKS. Would you mind explaining to me what exactly we're asking the program to execute?

Comment: You are taking the string value of `"..."` and multiplying it by an integer. Then you print the result. So if the integer is 2, the program multiplies `"..."` by 2 making `"..."` and `"..."`, then prints it resulting in `......`